# Use Local Maven Repository

Tags: ruby, buildr

How can I use jars that buildr loads by default into the local maven repo, rather than creating new (and repetitive) artifact tasks/dependencies?

For example, if were creating a scala or groovy application buildr would automatically download the scala or groovy jars respectively. Is it possible to include or merge these (default) jars into an application rather than creating a new artifact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is not possible or doable in a one step, easy way. I recommend you talk with us on the dev list of Buildr and we can probably create an enhancement for that.

For each library you would like to depend on, you usual can grep the code to find where we define the default jar we depend on.

For the example you mention, here are the default method to retrieve the default jars:

For Groovy: Buildr::Groovy::Groovyc.dependencies
For Scala: Buildr::Scala::Scalac.dependencies

I hope that helps.

Comment: To clarify the question, I've added an example. Thanks.

Comment: At the very least that is not documented. I don't think we thought of that. For specific cases, like Groovy or Scala, grepping the code will help find all the required artifacts. I'll try to find those.